# Can't Upload Image in PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm following code given at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp to upload image.

Instead of **$target_dir = "uploads/";** I'm specifying, path of local system where I would like to upload the image.

I'm getting success message at the end but I couldn't find Images at the specified location. Is there anything I have misunderstood or missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: echo your target_dir and check what path returns

Comment: check you folder access permission if you are using linux machine.

Comment: can you post your code to find error??

Answer (score 1):

If you run code in linux , you must have write permission in directory.
Chang permission directory to `777`

Comment: But if file uploading failed then give error message..she says she got success message

Answer (score 0):

check you folder access permission. It must be 755.

Comment: how could she get success message if file not uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me and I could only resolve after many tests.
I'm using linux 64, Ubuntu distribution and Vesta manager.

Here's the explanation:

The ***move_uploaded_file ($ filename, $ destination)*** function receives two parameters.

**The first** is a valid upload file, ie it was sent by the HTTP POST method of php.

**The second** is the name that the image file will be moved.
You are receiving success because **$filename** is a valid file and **$destination** is also a valid name.

If you print the contents of the file will have something like:

```
{
    "name": ["name-image.jpg"],
    "type": ["image/jpeg"],
    "tmp_name": ["/home/domain-name/tmp/phpVApV3h"],
    "error": [0],
    "size": [772014]
}
```

To use the *move_uploaded_file()* function you would have to pass the parameters quoted above.

Types of errors:

*UPLOAD_ERR_OK: 0*

*UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 1

*UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 2

*UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 6

*UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 7

*UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 8

*UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 3*

**[WRONG MODE]: passing only the new image name**

```
$target = 'new-image-name.jpg';

if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][0], $destination)){
    switch($file['error']){
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            echo "Error related to image size ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            echo "The temp directory was not found ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            echo "Could not save image to new location ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            echo "Error related to image extension ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            echo "Partial error while uploading image ...";
            break;
        default:
            echo 'An error has occurred!';
     }
}

echo 'The image upload was successful!';
```

**[CORRECT MODE]: passing the new name of the linked image with its absolute path**

```
$ target = '/home/domainname/public_html/assets/img/new-name-pic.jpg';

if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][0], $destination)){
    switch($file['error']){
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            echo "Error related to image size ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            echo "The temp directory was not found ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            echo "Could not save image to new location ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            echo "Error related to image extension ...";
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            echo "Partial error while uploading image ...";
            break;
        default:
            echo 'An error has occurred!';
     }
}

echo 'The image upload was successful!';
```

If you are using **Windows**, you can follow the same reasoning and also assign the absolute path to the new image name.

This worked for me and I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score -1):

try this code if you are uploade image in core php if you use wamp or xampp
this code is run

';
    if (**move_uploaded_file**($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }

     echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
     print_r($_FILES);

    print "";

?>